# Android string size

Tags: java, android, string, memory, size

I have a 24 KB file I download from a web server. I use this code to read it and put each line to an ArrayList.

```
        URL url = new URL(url);

        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is,1024*8);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bis, "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        int i = 0;
        while((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
            i++;
        }

        int p=0;
        for (String l : lines) {
            builder.append(String.valueOf(p)).append(": ");
            builder.append(l);
            builder.append("\n");
            p++;
        }
        String result = builder.toString();
```

The problem is that lines aren't added to stringBuilder since the builder reaches certain size. I am sure that the *for* cycle goes through each line (p and i values are the same) but only first 180 or so lines of text are added out of about 1000. I suspect that this has something to do with some android memory limits, because when I run the same code on Windows instead of the android app, the whole file is added to the string.

How do I put all lines to one string?

**EDIT:**
It turned out logcat doesn't display the whole string.

Comment: 24kb is certainly not the limit.

Comment: 1. Why use two loops instead of one (you need approximately two times the memory like that, but 24k should not be the problem). 2. Where do you see only "first180 or so" lines are added? This should definitely not happen. If that's what you see in the debugger: Eclipse as an example does not display strings with lots of text completely in the debugger but only the first "x lines or so". Could that be your problem?

Comment: how do you measure the number of lines added to your builder?

Comment: I should use just one loop, but I used two to make sure the problem occurs when appending strings to the builder. I see that 180 lines are added because when I display the string in the logcat, last line is "180: some text". This line adds the line number to the string: builder.append(String.valueOf(p)).append(": ");

Comment: A log in the logcat of a long string will only print the first  part like Axel said already. So this is bad checking. Better save to file.